# How to add Hyperlink to serializer when using rest_framework_nested

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In general, we can auto-generate model url with `serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer`, and the url will be `localhost/users/{user_pk}`.

With `rest_framework_nested`, the expected url could be `localhost/users/{user_pk}/calendars/{calendar_pk}`, so how to generate such url and add it to calendar serializer?

Comment: Why cannot you use nested routers for you requirements? Follow this link:https://pypi.python.org/pypi/drf-nested-routers

Comment: sorry about this, `rest_framework_nested` is one module of `drf-nested-routers`, but `drf-nested-routers` doesn't support adding hyperlink